# Unable to cast object of type 'MyAPI.Api.Middleware.MyFilter' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IFilterMetadata'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

My requirement is to modify the response from the controller before sending it back to the client.
I am trying to implement IActionResult interface.

```
public class MyFilter: IActionResult
    {
        ApiResponse _response = new ApiResponse();
        public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
        {
            
            var httpResponse = context.HttpContext.Response;
            if (httpResponse != null)
            {
                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == 200)
                {
                   
                    if (context.Result.GetType().Equals(typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult)))
                    {
                        _response.Response = ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult)context.Result).Value;
                        _response.Errors = null;
                        _response.IsSuccess = true;
                    }

                }
            }

            return ;
        }
    }
```

my program.cs has

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyFilter>();
builder.Services.AddAppServices();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDataContext(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddRepositories();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
```

my controller has the attribute

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(MyFilter))]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
    }
```

But when I invoke any of the controller action methods it doesn't reach and gives me an exception as response.

is there something I am missing completely?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement IActionFilter or IAsynActionFilter not IActionResult!
To create an Acton filter, we need to create a class that inherits either from the IActionFilter interface or IAsyncActionFilter interface or from the ActionFilterAttribute class which is the implementation of the IActionFilter, IAsyncActionFilter, and a few different interfaces as well:

```
public abstract class ActionFilterAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter, IFilterMetadata, 
    IAsyncActionFilter, IResultFilter, IAsyncResultFilter, IOrderedFilter
```

for example:

```
namespace ActionFilters.Filters
{
    public class ActionFilterExample : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            // our code before action executes
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // our code after action executes
        }
    }
}
```

then on your startup.cs (or program.cs in .net 6 and above):

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ActionFilterExample>();
```

Finally, to use a filter registered on the Action or Controller level, we need to place it on top of the Controller or Action as a ServiceType:

```
namespace AspNetCore.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [ServiceFilter(typeof(ActionFilterExample))]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "example", "data" };
        }

    }
}
```

read more: [codeMaze](https://code-maze.com/action-filters-aspnetcore/) [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: really appreciate your effort. But my requirement is to modify the actionresult of the controller which is possible via IActionResult or ActionFilterAttribute

Comment: OK, this solution meets your requirements, you can directly modify your http context as response in your filter class body. see the noted links for more info.  @Shekar.gvr